# change order on my object list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a object list as below:

```
ID   Name       PageOrder
1    Home       1
2    Product    2
3    Link       3
4    Help       4
```

Desired:

```
ID    Name      PageOrder
1     Home      1
3     Link      2
2     Product   3
4     Help      4
```

I'm coding this in C# as below. But I don't think the way i do is not best pratice. 
please advice.

```
public void OrderUp(int favouriteId)
    {
        UsFavourite currentFav = db.UsFavourites.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteID == favouriteId);

        // Get favourite by current favourite's order - 1
        UsFavourite tempFav = db.UsFavourites.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteOrder == (currentFav.FavouriteOrder - 1));

        if (tempFav != null)
        {
            //update tempFav
            tempFav.FavouriteOrder = currentFav.FavouriteOrder;
            Save();

            //update currentFav
            currentFav.FavouriteOrder = currentFav.FavouriteOrder - 1;
            Save();
        }

    }

    public void OrderDown(int favouriteId)
    {
        UsFavourite currentFav = db.UsFavourites.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteID == favouriteId);

        // Get favourite by current favourite's order + 1
        UsFavourite tempFav = db.UsFavourites.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteOrder == (currentFav.FavouriteOrder + 1));

        if (tempFav != null)
        {
            //update tempFav
            tempFav.FavouriteOrder = currentFav.FavouriteOrder;
            Save();

            //update currentFav
            currentFav.FavouriteOrder = currentFav.FavouriteOrder + 1;
            Save();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think the page order in your top table might be wrong. Should page order go 1,3,2,4? Ah my bad, you are trying to implement an increase/decrease feature.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this apart from the double Save(). You should only do one Save() (I assume Save() is written correctly). One possible 'better' implementation is to change it from OrderUp/OrderDown is to have one method where you also pass in an int i.e. +1 or -1 (or maybe +3) called ChangeFavourite which means you can get it down to a single method AND have the ability to drop/raise the position more than one place

Comment: I too think there's nothing wrong apart from the double `Save`. However, may I ask what happens if you delete a record? Do you make sure there are no gaps in your `PageOrder` numbers? If you have a sequence like 1, 5, 7 for any reason, this bit will crash.

Comment: Yup agreed with @Mudu - you must take care with deletions (you need to remove any gaps left OR make some other method of linking the list ;)

Comment: @Mudu Your question was what I am concerning about my code. At the momment, If one recored deleted, the whole code will be messed up.

Comment: @coder OK, I might have misunderstood you. I was thinking you're asking whether you are using EF API correctly on a purely technical level, apart from logical shortcomings... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks fine. As Paul said you should not use save twice. I would also be tempted to remove some duplication with the following

```
    public void OrderUp(int favouriteId)
    {
        ChangeOrder(false, favouriteId);

    }

    public void OrderDown(int favouriteId)
    {
        ChangeOrder(true, favouriteId);
    }
    private void ChangeOrder(bool OrderDown, int favouriteId)
    {           
        UsFavourite currentFav = db.UsFavourites.FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteID == favouriteId);

        // Get favourite by current favourite's order + 1
        UsFavourite tempFav;
        if (OrderDown)
        {
            tempFav = db.UsFavourites.OrderBy(m => m.FavouriteOrder).FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteOrder > (currentFav.FavouriteOrder));
        }
        else
        {
            tempFav = db.UsFavourites.OrderByDescending(m => m.FavouriteOrder).FirstOrDefault(m => m.FavouriteOrder < (currentFav.FavouriteOrder));

        }
        if (tempFav != null)
        {
            //update tempFav
            tempFav.FavouriteOrder = currentFav.FavouriteOrder;

            //update currentFav
            currentFav.FavouriteOrder = currentFav.FavouriteOrder + change;
            Save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you for suggesting. You code is perfect. Better than me. but what if a record deleted. Especially on  "tempFav" as it is getting a object by FavouriteOrder.

Comment: Added a solution to that problem :-)